# C split a wchar_t array

Tags: c++

```
wchar_t OrderingCode[100];
```

some code to a api

```
string looks like this L"AAAA-1-3-5-5\n\r\BBB-A-3-6-6-4"
```

I need to split the string in 2 at the line feed. I only finds sample when ppl loops the array. Are the any api functions to use as String.Split in C#

```
m_Result.SetWindowTextW(OrderingCode1);
m_Result.SetWindowTextW(OrderingCode2);
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at `strtok` function.

Comment: @rcs You should use `wcstok` for wide char strings when an API function is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) and then you can easily split it as follows:

```
std::vector< std::wstring > SplitString( const std::wstring& str, wchar_t ch )
{
    std::vector< std::wstring > ret;
    size_t startPos = 0;
    size_t endPos = str.find( ch, startPos );
    while( endPos != std::wstring::npos )
    {
        ret.push_back( str.substr( startPos, endPos ) );
        startPos = endPos + 1;
        endPos = str.find( ch, startPos );
    }
    ret.push_back( str.substr( startPos, str.length() );
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think he is using wchar_t for perfomance issues. Your answer is not an answer, but a suggestion. Rethink and answer exactly to his problem. Workaround is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    wchar_t * test, *next_token1;
    test = wcstok_s(OrderingCode, L"\n\r", &next_token1);
    if (test != NULL)
    {
      m_Result.SetWindowTextW(test);
      test = wcstok_s(nullptr, L"\n\r", &next_token1);
      if (test != NULL)
      {
        m_Result2.SetWindowTextW(test);
      }          
    }
```